# Angular8 post login call ends up with 400

Tags: angular, angular8

I am trying to make a login call to java back-end with Angular8 front-end.
The feature works fine in Postman but throw 400 in Angular.
The call looks like this:

```
login(username: string, password: string) {
        let headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.set("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        headers.set("Accept", "application/json");
        let options = {
            headers: headers,
            params: new HttpParams()
        }
        let payload = {"username": username, "password": password};
        let response = this.http.post<any>(environment.BASE_URL+'/api/auth/login', payload, options);
        console.log(response);
        return response;
    }
```

When I look into the browser console my request looks like this:

```
POST /api/auth/login HTTP/1.1 Host: localhost:8080 Connection:
    keep-alive Content-Length: 37 Accept: application/json, text/plain,
    */* Origin: http://localhost:4200 
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.102 Safari/537.36 
Content-Type: application/json
Referer: http://localhost:4200/login Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate,
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9,pl;q=0.8
```

For some reasons my headers I defined are not included and the content type is default "application/json", not x-form as I want. Payload is there but options are not. That probably is the reason of the error so why my headers are not accepted, what is wrong here?

Comment: The post method returns an Observable. So you need to subscribe on it to log it.
`this.http.post<any>(environment.BASE_URL+'/api/auth/login', payload, options).subscribe(res => console.log(res));` but this doesn't solve you problem :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, a really working example look like this:

```
login(username: string, password: string): Observable<LoggedUser> {
        let headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers = headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
        headers = headers.append('Accept', 'application/json');

        let params = new HttpParams();
        params = params.set('username', username);
        params = params.set('password', password);
        const options = {
            headers,
            params
        };
        return this.http.post<LoggedUser>(environment.BASE_URL + '/api/auth/login', {}, options);
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

Persume your backend looks something like this:

```
@RequestMapping(path = "/api/auth/login", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public Collection getLoginData(@RequestParam("username") String username, 
    @RequestParam("password") String password) {
    return this.service.getLoginData(username, password);
}
```

Try it with FormData

```
public getLoginData(username: string, password: string): any {
  const data = new FormData();
  data.append('username', username);
  data.append('password', password);
  return this.http.post<any>(environment.BASE_URL + '/api/auth/login', data);
}
```

Comment: Your answer is also nearly right but data must be "referenced", similar to below example of Ammar

Answer (score 1):

Try this code. You have to set the reference to original object.

```
login(username: string, password: string) {
        let headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers = headers.append("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        headers = headers.append("Accept", "application/json");
        let options = {
            headers: headers,
            params: new HttpParams()
        }
        let payload = {"username": username, "password": password};
        let response = this.http.post<any>(environment.BASE_URL+'/api/auth/login', payload, options);
        console.log(response);
        return response;
}
```

Comment: in the first glance I couldn't see the different :) So small change but make a difference. The only thing is the x-form payload should go to HttpParams, not to the the payload and it works. Another way is to use URLSearchParams as a payload, I think (didn't try)